# Strange usage of 頂く

Tags: meaning

From Danganronpa:

> 希望ヶ峰学園へようこそ…まずは、簡単な操作説明をさせて頂きます。
> 左スティックで、画面上の照準をご操作**頂けます**

From a google search, apparently 操作いただきます is not that uncommon of a phrase, but it doesn't make sense to me considering any of the meanings I can find for 頂く in a dictionary.

Comment: The fact that it's ご操作 is relevant. How familiar are you with keigo?

Comment: I am familiar with phrases such as "ご理解頂きますようお願い致します" but I still don't really see how 操作頂く makes sense

Comment: Wouldn`t the correct 敬語 be something like ご操作になれます?

Comment: I guess the other part that's weird to me is that it seems like the game is essentially saying "I can receive this from you" when it seems to be trying to say "You can do this".

Comment: Does this answer your question:  [ご～いただけます vs. ご～になれます](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1078/78)

Comment: It does! Nonstandard usages make learning stuff like this so much harder...