# 電話をくださる subject identification

Tags: grammar

I encounter sentences that mix two grammar concepts: "てくださる” and "ということです" :

> 林さんからお電話がありまして、４時ごろもう一度電話をくださるということです。

Because I don't identify the subject of the "くださる”: which of these interpretations is correct?

> **私が**電話をくださるということです。
> **林さんが**電話をくださるということです。

I'm not sure if the meaning is that Hayashi will call back at 4:00 or if he asks to be called back at 4:00?

Comment: I think you've already started to notice since it was just edited, but there is no grammar point てくださる in these sentences. くださる is here used as a verb, and is simply the respectful version of くれる.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the following answer says, the core of くださる is *to give*.

- [When can I exchange くださる for いただく in expressions of gratitude?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/957/45489)

ということです is a construction expressing hearsay. Thus もう一度電話をくださるということです means *I was told that (subj.) would give a call again*. Since it is saying *again*, you can deduce (more or less without knowing much grammar) that the subject is 林さん.

Also by the nature of くださる, 私 will never be the subject to くださる.

Answer (score 1):

Original text:

> 林さんからお電話がありまして、４時ごろもう一度電話をくださるということです。

My translation (supposing that 4時 == 4PM):

> Rin / Lin / Hayashi informed me on the phone that there will be another incoming call around 4PM.

According to this context:

- いうことです -> informed me ******
- お電話がありまして -> ***** in the phone

I hope this can help you comprehend the original text easiser.

Comment: "another incoming call" > To me it sounds like there is a 90% percent chance that it's not *some* incoming call, but that 林さん will call again around 4pm.

Comment: @Earthliŋ However, Nihongo prefers to omit the grammatical subject. I don't dare to assert that the subject is 林さん in this case. The incoming call target is the one who speaks this sentence, still.