# Confused about sentences: 当たる and 出る

Tags: translation

I tried to read a blog entry but some sentences are confusing me.

> 握手会でもファンの方が当たったよ！って嬉しそうに言ってくれた

I know all the words and the grammar involved but 当たったよ！is confusing me. The verb meaning I've learned doesn't make any sense here.

For the following case, I'm lost when I try to identify the subject.

最初は誰の手もかりず振りVを見て一人で覚えたあと
るかに細かい振りを教えてもらいながらフリを覚えたって言ってたけど
is it the blog author (安奈) or 高塚ちゃん ? 
Since 言ってた means that the author heard someone saying it, the author is the subject from the beginning ?

高塚ちゃんに出てもらえて良かったなって思います 
Here it's the same as the first one, how I'm supposed to understand 出てもらえて in this sentence ?

I add the blog entry link because I guess it will be easier to understand it with the context : https://plus.google.com/116252784914637564000/posts/fNufttEs3vv

Maybe it's very basic questions, but I tried several times to understand and I failed those parts.

Answer (score 4):

> 握手会でもファンの方が当たったよ！って嬉しそうに言ってくれた

Xが当たる in this context means "to win X", where X is a ticket, prize, lottery, etc. 安奈's fan said to her, 「（チケットが）当たったよ！」 = "I won it (=the ticket of the show)!"

> 最初は誰の手もかりず振りVを見て一人で覚えたあと るかに細かい振りを教えてもらいながらフリを覚えたって言ってた

The omitted subject of all these actions is 高塚ちゃん. 高塚ちゃん studied the choreography alone first, then 高塚ちゃん learned it with the help of るか. And that's what 高塚ちゃん said to the author, 安奈.

> 高塚ちゃんに出てもらえて良かったなって思います

出る here means 出演する. Looks like you already know the meaning of "verb + もらう" pattern, which is [described here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14828/5010). The author, 安奈 is glad 高塚ちゃん will be on stage.

Comment: Now I understand it so much better, thank you ! Yes indeed, I know the pattern "verb + もらう".
And "ながら" in the second sentence, it's used as "while" (ex: while she was ...) ?