# きれいな鳥に連れてってもらいます

Tags: translation

Someone asked his/her friend "What did you do after the wedding party" and his/her friend said:

> ええ、すこしながいやすみをとって、きれいな鳥に連れてってもらいます。

I don't understand the meaning of "鳥に" here, and "連れてってもらいます" here .

Comment: What are you talking about? Please read through your question again. I don't understand your question. I just figured out that the friend was a mental lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

きれいな鳥に連れてってもらいます literally means "I will have [my husband] take me to a beautiful bird."

- きれいな: beautiful
- 鳥: bird
- に: (destination marker)
- 連れて: te-form of 連れる "to take someone (to somewhere)"
- って: contraction for いって, which is the te-form of the subsidiary verb [いく](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)
- もらいます: masu-form of もらう (implies someone does a favor for you; see [What is the meaning of もらう here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14828/5010))

Of course it makes little sense. Perhaps you have mixed 鳥【とり】 (bird) and **島【しま】** (**island**)? Going to a beautiful island for a honeymoon is certainly a common thing to do.