# how do you say "to get someone to do something" in japanese?

Tags: syntax

In spanish, we can combine "to do" (hacer) with other verbs to create new actions. for example, "to get someone to sleep" it's "hacer dormir" (hacer = do , dormir = sleep) . In the same way we can combine "to do" with objects to create new actions like "hacer viajes" just like japanese use "ryokou suru" for the same meaning. One very naive assumption could be may be you can also combine "suru" with other verbs, to get the meaning of "to get someone to do something", just like we do in spanish (since in spanish and japanese we combine them with a noun in the same way for the same meaning). But most likely not, since this seems to be a very intrinsically feature to latin languages. Anyway, asking it wont hurt I supppose, can you combine "suru" with other verbs, to get the meaning of "getting someone to do something" ? I've heard what for me looked like strange combinations of languages features in japanese recently like, "okay shimashita" (or I completely missunderstood the sentence)

Comment: https://www.japanistry.com/japanese/the-causative/

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14828/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e3%82%82%e3%82%89%e3%81%86-here/14829#14829

Comment: so the answer would be there is an inflection for that, and no, you can't combine suru with verbs like you do in spanish?

Comment: @Pablo I'm not sure what you mean by combine する with verbs --  する IS a verb, and there are a class of verbs considered する verbs (which are basically a set of activity nouns with the verb する).

What I do know is that the verb 'hacer' in Spanish is probably closer to the meaning of 'make' in English, than it is to the meaning of 'do'. But even that translation makes no sense in Japanese, because Japanese has a conjugation specifically for causing an action to occur (have something be done/made), or, 'hacer'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure a quick search would give you all this basic information, but there are verb tenses especially for that.

> する->させる : to make someone do something.
>   する->させられる : to be made to do something by someone.
>   食べる->食べさせる : I made someone eat.
>   食べる->食べさせられる : I was made to eat by someone.

You can also use してもらう. Which basically mean "I will have you do this"

Comment: 「食べされる」っていうのはないですね・・「食べられる」が passive "~is eaten" で「食べさせられる」が causative passive "I'm made to eat" ですよね

Comment: @Chocolate ありがとうございました。なかなか恥ずかしいミスですね。

Comment: `to be done something by someone.`<- ってよくわかんないんですけど、「させられる」って causative passive だから "to be made to do something" とか・・・？

Comment: @Chocolate また恥ずかしいミスしちゃったな。本当に申し訳ないです。先の「される」の説明のままでした。Chocolateさんの日本語も英語も、かなり上手ですね。海外で住んだことがあるでしょうか？