# When you ask someone to do a favour, what is the difference between くれますか and もらいますか?

Tags: giving-and-receiving

I know when I am describing a situation I should use:

> 彼はドアをあけてくれました。

or

> 私は彼にドアをあけて貰いました。

But what about in a question? I saw this phrase in a Japanese TV show, when the speaker wants another person to leave the room first:

> 先に行ってくれますか？

In this situation, can I say 先に行って貰いますか？

Please explain the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ok to use ～て下さりました instead of ～ていただきました?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/402/is-it-ok-to-use-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a6%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%95%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f-instead-of-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f)

Comment: ^ でもそのスレッドには、「もら**え**ますか？」が出てこないようですけど・・

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 先に行ってくれますか？ -- Will you go first?

You can rephrase it as:

先に行ってもら**え**ますか？ -- *lit.* Can I have you go first?

(もらえる is the potential form of もらう)

Comment: Same goes with the honorific form (尊敬語): 「先に行ってくださいますか？」(Would you go first?) 「先に行っていただ**け**ますか？」(*lit.* Could I have you go first?) not 「先に行っていただきますか？」You'd use potential いただ**け**る.