# What are the nuances between くれますか vs くれませんか in terms of requests?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I know there are more politer forms like itadaku but just focusing on the masu and masen aspects, which is politer? What are the nuances? Which is more forceful-sounding?

Answer (score 3):

As so often, it depends on the context.

Just translating them into English should be enough of a clue.  「～くれますか」 is simply "Will you give me ～?" (or "Will you do ～ for me?" in the case of 「～てくれますか」).  「～くれませんか」 is simply "Will you not give/do for me ～?", which of course can be rearranged to be "Won't you give/do for me ～?"

I would say that more often than not, ～くれませんか is a little softer because it is more like you're politely asking for help with something, and ～くれますか is more straightforward and blunt.  But again, depending on context, different meanings can come across.  If your friend asks you

> ￥1000貸してくれない？　→　Won't you lend me ￥1000? (= "Can I borrow ￥1000?")

they are asking a favour of you.  But if your boss asks you

> 17:00までに書類を揃えといてくれない？　→　Won't you prepare the documents for me by 17:00?

s/he's obviously not asking you to do them a favour; it's a very polite and indirect command.

Now if you substituted くれる into both these sentences, they'd have a completely different feel.  "Are you going to do ～ for me?"  This sounds less amicable, like the asker just wants to know the facts.  It could even convey a bit of annoyance of unmet expectations.  ("Are you going to lend me the money (or not)?", "Are you going to prepare the documents (you lazy worker)?")

---

Lastly, just to note, the polite (respectful) form of くれる is ***not*** いただく; it is くださる.  いただく is the polite (humble) form of もらう.  Refer to [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/402/78) for more information on those.

Comment: Out of curiosity is there any reason why くれへん is being used here rather than くれない?

Comment: @virmaior:  Out of habit.  Didn't even realize I'd put it in.